# SQLPLUS connection to different dbs

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Hello i want to connect to following dbs in loop and execute statements on each:

```
conn support/support@sp0666to 
conn support/support@sp0667to 
conn support/support@sp0668to
```

Is there any way to do this in sqlplus?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: `connect to following dbs in loop`..not clear why you want to connect it in loops. You can connect them individually,run your statements and exit connection

Comment: `conn support/support@sp0666to
set lines 1500 pages 10000
set colsep ';'
set sqlprompt ''
set heading on
set headsep off
set newpage none
column tm new_value file_time noprint
select to_char(sysdate, 'DDMMYYYY_HH24.MI') tm from dual ;
spool C:\Users\NANCHEV\Desktop\parked.csv
select EMPLOYEE,AUTHORIZED,TIME,DAT,WORKSTATION, from EMPLOYEE where status =25;
spool off;
exit`  I want to execute this on each connection and save the data in csv. Can you assist with some code or tutorial?

Comment: The problem is that they are 668 , not just the three in the example :(

Comment: @user3450687 are you wanting a file per database?

Comment: @user3450687 Is this a one-time thing or do you need to frequently run statements on large sets of databases?  Do you need to run SQL*Plus scripts, or just regular SQL and PL/SQL statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one script (doWork.sql) that contains the majority of what you want to do:

```
conn &1/&2@&3

select EMPLOYEE, AUTHORIZED, TIME, DAT, WORKSTATION
  from EMPLOYEE
 where status = 25;
```

In a separate script (goToWork.sql):

```
set lines 1500 pages 10000
set colsep ';'
set sqlprompt ''
set heading on
set headsep off
set newpage none column tm new_value file_time noprint 

select to_char(sysdate, 'DDMMYYYY_HH24.MI') tm from dual;

accept user
accept pass

spool C:\Users\NANCHEV\Desktop\parked.csv

@@doWork &user &pass sp0666to 
@@doWork &user &pass sp0667to 
@@doWork &user &pass sp0668to 

spool off;
exit
```

If you want separate files, then move the two spool commands to the doWork.sql file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to run the same set of queries for each database, I'd create a script file (e.g. main_statements.sql) containing those statements.

Then, if the list of databases was static, I'd create a second script file (e.g. run_me.sql) in the same directory, with contents along the lines of:

```
connect &&user/&&password@db1
@@main_statements.sql

connect &&user/&&password@db2
@@main_statements.sql

connect &&user/&&password@db3
@@main_statements.sql

...
```

If, however, the databases are static but the list is contained in a database somewhere, then I'd write a script (e.g. run_me.sql) that generates a script, something like:

```
set echo off
set feedback off
set verify off

spool databases_to_run_through.sql

select 'connect '||username||'/'||password||'@'||database_name||chr(10)||
       '@@main_statements.sql'
from   list_of_databases_to_query;

spool off;

@@databases.run_through.sql
```

N.B. untested. Also, I have assumed that your table contains the usernames and passwords for each db that needs to be connected to; if that's not the case, you'll have to work out how to handle them; maybe they're all the same (in which case, you can hardcode them - or better yet, use substitution variables (e.g. `&&username`) to avoid having to store them in a plain file. You'd then have to enter them at runtime.

You'll also need to run the script from the same directory, otherwise you could end up with the generated script not being created in the same directory as your main_statements.sql equivalent script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you can use oracle DBLink to connect to different dbs just like your example.